# Пройтись по ссылкам на странице результатов поиска Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Нужно перейти по ссылкам из результатов поиска.  Вот код.

```
public void firstFiltersSet() {
    // Create Chrome driver
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    //Maximize browser window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    // Open test page
    String url = "website";
    driver.get(url);
    
    
    List<WebElement> adsList= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ads-list-photo-item-title ']/a"));
    int addListLength = adsList.size();
       for (int i = 0; i <= addListLength - 1; i++) {
           adsList.get(i).click();
           WebElement currentAdvertisment  = new WebDriverWait(driver,  10)
               .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//header[@class='adPage__header']/h1")));     
           driver.navigate().back();
      }
```

В итоге, происходит переход на первую ссылку, возврат к списку результатов поиска и тесты падает с ошибкой `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`.

Как правильно обработать данные кейс ? Заранее спасибо